# simulation protocol socket java

Tags: java, sockets

Two clients start their communication by means of a TTP server. The first fundamental problem are the messages because the various messages always have a different structure based on feedback from various hosts. I thought about using a LinkedList with socket TPC.

//server

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {

final int port=12345;
try {

    ServerSocket serversocket=new ServerSocket(port);


    System.out.println("TTP on-line")
        while (true) {
        Socket clientSocket=serversocket.accept();
        System.out.println("accept "+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()+" on port "+clientSocket.getPort());

        ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());


        LinkedList<Message> inList = new LinkedList<>();

        Message inMsg = null;
        inList =(LinkedList<Message>)inFromClient.readObject();
        inMsg = inList.pop();

           /* Send the modified Message object back */
        outToClient.writeObject(inMsg);  

    }


}
catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println("Server Error: " + e.getMessage());
System.err.println("Localized: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
System.err.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
System.err.println("To String: " + e.toString());
```

//client

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int port=12345;
        System.out.println("Client Started...");


try {

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
    ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

    LinkedList<Message> msgList = new LinkedList<>();
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setIp             //make
    msgList.push(msg);

    // Send the Message Object to the server 
    outToServer.writeObject(msgList);  

     // Retrive the Message Object from server 
    LinkedList<Message> inFromServerList = new LinkedList<>();
    Message msgFrmServer = null;
    inFromServerList = (LinkedList<Message>)inFromServer.readObject();
    msgFrmServer = inFromServerList.pop();


    //Print out the recived Message 
    msgFrmServer.getMessage();


    clientSocket.close();
}

       catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println("Client Error: " + e.getMessage());
System.err.println("Localized: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
System.err.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
```

the problem is the cast object to linkedlist... .

//Message

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

private String ipTTp;
private String ipM;
private String ipD;

public Message ( String ipT, String ipMit, String ipDest) {

    this.ipTTp= ipT;
    this.ipM=ipMit;
    this.ipD=ipDest;

}

public Message ( ) {

}

public void setIpm (String ipm) {

    this.ipM=ipm;
}

public void setIpdes (String ipd) {

    this.ipD=ipd;
}

public void getMessage () {

    System.out.println("ip mit: "+ipMi);
    System.out.println("ip dest: "+ipDest);

}
```

What could I do?. I missed the logic of the problem ?. I tried to serialize the Message class but I always get warning. I state that I am not an expert java ...

Comment: What is the server sending? Is a Message? A MessageList? Please post the full text of any and all error messages or exceptions that you see. Also, are you making sure to use threading to prevent your code from freezing?

Comment: Thanks, now, what error messages or exceptions do you receive?

Comment: The error is the cast when i make readobject to linkedlist<message  >

Comment: When we ask for the error message, you should always post the complete error message, not a paraphrasing of it. The details matter.

Comment: sorry man this is the output: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast inFromServerList = (LinkedList<Message>)inFromServer.readObject(); ^ required: LinkedList<Message> found: Object 1 warning.
I serializable the class Message but the warning stay...

Comment: A warning is nothing to worry about, and is going to be expected I think. Are you getting an exception when running the code? Are you getting the expected data?

Comment: i want delete this warning. the exception on runtime is:
Client Error: Message cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList
Localized: Message cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList
Stack Trace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1ed1817d

Comment: It looks like you're receiving a Message object there, not a LinkedList.

Comment: I'm not understanding where ... you can help me? ..